# GraphQL schema management

Tags: plugins, graphql, ide

Is there a plugin or way to rearrange a single graphql schema file. Basically I want my graphql schema to be more organized. For example, All types should be at the top, followed by type Query followed by Mutations followed by Subscription and so on. Something similar to the code arrangement we do with class files in Intellij or other IDEs (i.e, constants at the top, followed by private variable, methods and so on)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! There is the great package [called `format-graphql` by Gajus Kuizinas](https://github.com/gajus/format-graphql) that does exactly this -- enforcing consistent style on your schema. It is somewhat opinionated, so you can either 1) deal with the current custom options provided when you configure the package or 2) fork it, and [rewrite this core utility](https://github.com/gajus/format-graphql/blob/master/src/utilities/formatSdl.js) to achieve the desired effect.